# How to solve this integral with u-sub?

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble solving this integral, I just can't seem to get it using u-substitution, what else can I try?
[image: question]

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2432588/problems-with-double-integration Are you guys from the same class lol.

Comment: You can integrate with respect to $x$ directly. Then, **if** the integrand over $(-a, a)$ is an odd function, the integral will be $0$. What conditions will make the integrand odd? Can the integrand ever be made even?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by writing the integral like this,

$$\int_{-a}^a \left(\int_b^c y^{2m+1} e^{xy^{2n}} \mathrm dx\right) \mathrm dy$$

The integral wrt x should be easy enough to compute directly. Then, consider the parity of the integrand that you end up with. Note that,

$$f(-x) = f(x) \implies \int_{-a}^a f(x) \mathrm dx = 2\int_0^a f(x) \mathrm dx$$
$$f(-x) = -f(x) \implies \int_{-a}^a f(x) \mathrm dx = 0$$

Comment: does this only work with -a to a?

Comment: Yes, it's due to the symmetry of odd/even functions. If you want proofs see: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definite_Integral_of_Odd_Function and https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definite_Integral_of_Even_Function